# How to make it better, function with logical operator and

Tags: javascript

My function doesn't count the price correctly. Price depends on three selects.

First select has 2 option

Second select has 3 option

Third select has 2 option.

So i have 2*3*2 = 12 cases of possible price.
 Then I put price into div by using innerHTML.
code:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ajoLgL4o/][1]
```

it is possible to make it easier? I am trying to do 12 if statments with two "and" operators. If I had 10 options in each select i would have 1000 cases...so i think i do it wrong.

Comment: You should post the related code in your question. Do not circumvent the SO rules.

Comment: Tell us the logic you are using. Its not clear in jsfiddle

Comment: Please don't name your variables with single letters, makes it hard for others to understand your code

Comment: Each option in the drop-down can have custom `data-value` attributes. Use those in your calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store a value with each option then use the values of the selected options to do the calculation:

```
<select id="myselect1">
    <option value="22.00">Example</option>
</select>

document.getElementById("myselect1").value
```

Comment: Remember to call `parseFloat()` or you'll end up with NaN when you run calculations